# Visual Studio 2013 Test Explorer StackTrace for failed unit test shows "no source available" instead of link to failed line

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I created a simple unit test in a C# project:

```
[TestMethod]
public void DoSomething()
{
    // Act

    // assert
    Assert.Fail("blah");
}
```

When I run this, the Test Explorer does not hyperlink to the line that failed (the Assert) and does not show the line number. Instead if I hover over the line it shows "no source available".

```
Test Name:  DoSomething
Test FullName:  BlahBlah.DoSomething
Test Source:c:\Src\BlahBlahTest.cs : line 223
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:04.1933182

Result Message: Assert.Fail failed. blah
Result StackTrace:  at BlahBlahTest.DoSomething()
```

I deleted the .suo file and the test is set to full debugging.
I also have Resharper installed and its test runner also doesn't link to the failed line.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: old question, but do you know what was the problem? Is it possible that the project was build in release configuration, without debugging symbols?